# Ordering of collection changes depending on call method

Tags: collection, event-observer

I have the following piece of code:

```
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(1);
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$collection->addCategoryFilter($model);
$collection->addAttributeToSort('product_id','DESC');

foreach ($collection as $p ) {

    var_dump($p->getId());

}
```

This basically loops over the products within a category (with the ID of 1).

The strange behaviour I am experiencing is that the `var_dump` of the product ID varies in sort order depending where I call it from. I am calling it from two places: a controller and an observer (catalog_category_save_commit_after).

Is there anything I am missing? The ID's should be printed in the same order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you run these code `echo "<pre>"; print_r($collection->getData());` you will come to know that there is no attribute with name `product_id` instead use `entity_id`.

so that your code becomes `$collection->addAttributeToSort('entity_id','DESC');`